# Force relative URIs with nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a static site setup as follows:

```
location /cool {
    alias /var/www/cool/build;
    index index.html;
}
```

This serves the `index.html` file, but all the files that `index.html` references fail because they're relative to `/`. e.g., it's trying to load `mydomain.com/styles.css` rather than `mydomain.com/cool/styles.css`.

Rather than rewriting every link on the whole site to not have a preceding `/`, is there any way I can make nginx treat these links to be relative to `/cool`?